# simple Oracle select statement syntax

Tags: oracle

I am looking for a best syntax to have the following result

In my table (Fruit),

```
Name         Color
-----------  --------
Apple        Green
Apple        Red
Banana       Yellow
Banana       White
Watermelon   Red
Watermelon   White
```

My search criteria :
 Color : "Green" & "Red"

```
SELECT distinct(Name) FROM Fruit
WHERE Color = 'Green' OR Color = 'Red'
```

This will return "Apple" and "Watermelon

How will be the SQL statement (Oracle) like if I want only "Apple" be the result?

Thank you!!

Comment: Just remove 'Color = red'. That would give you Apple.

Comment: thanks for the comment, 
If in the table there is another fruit, let's say Pear which is also Green in color, if I use only "Color = Green" , Both Apple & Pear will be selected.

Comment: Well it seems you've got it answered. I guess no need to continue this discussion

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name
FROM   FRUIT
WHERE  color IN ( 'Red', 'Green' )
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT color ) = 2;
```

You could also use collections to do the same thing:

```
CREATE FruitColorTableType AS TABLE OF FRUIT.COLOR%TYPE;
/

SELECT DISTINCT
       Name
FROM   FRUIT f
WHERE  FruitColorTableType( 'Red', 'Green' )
       SUBMULTISET OF
       CAST( MULTISET(
         SELECT Color
         FROM   FRUIT c
         WHERE  c.name = f.name
       ) AS FruitColorTableType );
```

OR:

```
SELECT name
FROM   FRUIT
WHERE  color MEMBER OF FruitColorTableType( 'Red', 'Green' )
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT color ) = 2;
```

and if you rewrite it as a function/procedure you can pass the collection in as an argument and use the `CARDINALITY()` function rather than hard coding the size of the collection.

(Not tested these last two queries so there might be some typos)

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear why you want "Apple" to be returned but not "Watermelon".  My guess is that you want to return only those `name` values that appear with a `color` of both Red and Green.  Assuming that is the case

```
SELECT name
  FROM fruit
 WHERE color IN ('Red', 'Green')
 GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(distinct color) = 2
```

or

```
SELECT name
  FROM fruit
 WHERE color = 'Red'
INTERSECT
SELECT name
  FROM fruit
 WHERE color = 'Green'
```

would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking both conditions

```
Select name from fruit  where color ='Red' 
and name in (select  name from fruit
where color='Green');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `rownum = 1` in the where clause but it's dirty.. Is like limit 1 in MySQL

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
Let's say, If I want the result be "Watermelon", I search by color = Red or White. and I use rownum=1, "Apple" will be the result but not watermelon...